# Converting GeoPoint to String, then convert that string back to GeoPoint

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, gps

Bit of a weird question.

I'm passing data from one activity to another - specifically two GeoPoints. But, as I discovered, you can't pass an ArrayList of type GeoPoint. I thought of converting them to strings and passing them through in an ArrayList of type string (so, geopoint1.tostring()), which went fine, but I have no idea how to then convert them back to a GeoPoint in the next activity.

What I'm doing might be totally mental and stupid, but I just can't seem to think of any other way.

I've posted this quick question to try and get some quick responses, but if you need any more info just ask me, I'll put it straight up.

BTW, I'm passing the data using intent.putExtra, etc.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getLatitudeE6()/getLongitudeE6()`  of [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) returns an int.

So you can use your coordinate in an array of int and send it with 
`putExtra(String name, int[] value)` from the intent

```
int[] myGeoPoints = { 30, 50 };
putExtra("myCoordinates", myGeoPoints)
```

and retrieve the array from the target activity with `getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray`

```
getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("myCoordinates")
```

Or you can put the latitude/longitude with different key in the Intent's Extra  with
`putExtra(String name, int value)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is Android but I cant resist answering to a beautiful New Start.

I suppose there is a more straightforward way to pass a GeoPoint around (fellow SO members, help me out here) but if you pass it around as a String, here's what you can do:

Parse latitude and longitude out of the String. I guess you just have to split it by ',' and convert the two parts to int (you'll have to verify this by looking at the result of the GeoPoint.toString()).

```
String[] separated = yoGeoPointAsString.split(",");
// I suppose, this will contain latitude
int latitudeE6 = Integer.parseInt(separated[0]); 
// I suppose, this will contain longitude
int longitudeE6 = Integer.parseInt(separated[1]);
```

once you have extracted the two int values from the string, you just call the constructor:

```
GeoPoint gp = GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much, i think i was thinking far too much into it.. think my brain is fried.